# $h:X\to X$ endomorphism of module $X$ over $R$ satisfying $h\circ h = h$. Prove X = Im(h)\oplus Ker(h)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $h:X\to X$ denote an endomorphism of a module $X$ over $R$ satisfying $h\circ h = h$. Prove

$$X = Im(h)\oplus Ker(h)$$

I have this theorem:

> If the composition $h=g\circ f$ of two homomorphisms $f:X\to Y$ and
>   $g:Y\to Z$ of modules $X,Y,Z$ over $R$ is an isomorphism, then the
>   following statements hold:
>
> i) $f$ is a monomorphism
>
> ii) $g$ is an epimorphism
>
> iii) The module $Y$ is decomposable into the direct sum of $Im(f)$ and
>    $Ker(g)$

Wel, the composition $h\circ h$ is surely a bijection, and since i'ts an endomorphism, it's a homomorphism. So should it follow directly from this theorem?

Comment: Why should $h\circ h $ be a bijection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=(x-h(x))+h(x)$, $x-h(x)\in Ker(h), h(x)\in Imh$. Suppose $y\in Kerh\cap Im h$, there exists $x$ such that $h(x)=y$ since $y\in Im(h)$, we have $h(y)=0=h^2(x)=h(x)=y$. This implies that $Imh\cap Ker h=0$.